# How do I use boost bcp?

Tags: c++, sql-server, boost, bcp, path-variables

I have the bcp tool, it came pre-built with the boost installer. I'd like to extract the dependencies I need from boost into a smaller file, since I'd like to be able to build this project at school. I'm trying to use bcp, but I don't understand how to use it, despite these instructions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html#bcp.syntax

I've tried typing: bcp boost/thread.hpp /"E:\documents\Dropbox\School\Comp 445\Comp445_Assign2_v2\boost2" from the command prompt, from within my boost folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_51

It just spits out a "usage" guide: 
bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile

I've also tried: bcp timed_mutex /, bcp mutex / to no avail.

I find this really confusing; it doesn't look at all like what they say in the boost documentation, and I'm not sure what a lot of this means in any case. I've found a lot of threads where people recommend bcp, but I've had a hard time finding any where people are asking how to use it.

Comment: "bcp {dbtable | query}" Are you sure you're running the boost utility and not e.g. SQL Server's Bulk Copy tool? Do you have a boost BCP executable that you've compiled? Is it in your current folder or in the system PATH?

Comment: @Rup you should probably post this as an answer since the BCP for SQL gives that same error message.

Comment: @rhalbersma Thanks but that's only half the problem, though: that tells him what he's doing wrong, though, but not how to actually make it work.

Comment: @Rup see my answer for how to fix it

Comment: when posting Boost related questions, make sure to add the C++ tag to get more people to look at it.

Comment: @rhalbersma Oh, OK - I'd assumed there'd be more to it than that e.g. he might not have actually compiled it, or it might turn out to be a shell script or something.

Answer (score 5):

As @Rup pointed out in the comments, the likely error is that you have SQL Server's Bulk Copy Program present on your system. That program is also named `bcp.exe` and is most likely present in your `PATH` environment variable. The Boost `bcp` is either not present in your `PATH`, or is preceded by the SQL `bcp` (Windows will stop searching for other programs as soon as it finds a match).

To call the Boost bcp you should either

1. Rename it to something else (e.g. `boost-bcp`) and [**update your `PATH` variable**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) to reflect that and make sure there are no other conflicting names. Then call with "boost-bcp" --YOUR_OPTIONS.
2. Call the Boost `bcp` with the full path to its current location, e.g. "C:\Boost\bcp.exe" --YOUR_OPTIONS