# How to run Boost bcp on windows?

Tags: c++, boost

I've built bcp on windows with VS14.1 and no matter what I do I keep getting the following error:

`std::exception Found a closing ) with no corresponding openening parenthesis.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '?+(([(<].*>>>HERE>>>)?$)?'.`

I tried escaping slashes via double slashes, absolute path, etc, but none of them seems to work. My boost version is 1.66

```
./bcp.exe D:/boost/boost_1_66_0_precompiled/boost/shared_ptr.hpp D:/boost/boost_1_66_0_precompiled

./bcp.exe D:\\boost\\boost_1_66_0_precompiled\\boost\\shared_ptr.hpp D:\\boost\\boost_1_66_0_precompiled

./bcp.exe boost/shared_ptr.hpp extract
```

Funnily enough, when I deliberately add a wrong directory, it shows "Destination path does not exist" instead.

Comment: You're not running into this problem by any chance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16319780/256138

Comment: @rubenvb I tried it with full path and still didn't work. I checked the path as well. There is the MS's BCP, but is not called. Besides, I believe the above error is from boost library regex.hpp?

Comment: Right, could be, just making sure we're not barking up the wrong tree.